# Incompatibility with Mysql 5.7(Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list)

Tags: mysql

When I execute the following query I receive an Exception:

> Error Code: 3065  Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT
> list, references      column 'webstore.level_depth' which is not in
> SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

My Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id_parent, c.id_category, cl.name, cl.description, cl.link_rewrite
FROM `pj_category_shop` cs, `pj_category` c
INNER JOIN `pj_category_lang` cl ON (c.`id_category` = cl.`id_category` AND cl.`id_lang` = 1 AND cl.id_shop = 2 )
WHERE (c.`active` = 1 OR c.`id_category` = 2)
  AND cs.`id_category` = c.`id_category`
  AND cs.`id_shop` = 2
  AND c.`id_category` != 1
  AND `level_depth` <= 2
  AND c.id_category IN (
    SELECT id_category
    FROM `pj_category_group`
    WHERE `id_group` IN (3)
  )
ORDER BY `level_depth` ASC, cl.`name` ASC;
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 29):

I have find the answer for my question.Actually mysql 5.7 contains '***ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY***' in sql mode.So we can't perform orderby in the element that is not in select list.we have to change it from

```
'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

into

```
'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

We can done this by executing the following queries

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

Comment: Actually, you should only need to execute one of them. GLOBAL variables affect the overall operation of the server and SESSION variables affect operations for individual client connections. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html).

Comment: To use the value from MySQL 5.6, drop all but the last option: `set global SQL_MODE="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";`

Answer (score 4):

`ORDER BY` column should be column listed in the `SELECT` list

Add `c.level_depth` in your select list

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id_parent, c.id_category, cl.name, cl.description, cl.link_rewrite, c.level_depth
    FROM `pj_category_shop` cs, `pj_category` c
    INNER JOIN `pj_category_lang` cl ON (c.`id_category` = cl.`id_category` AND cl.`id_lang` = 1 AND cl.id_shop = 2 )
    WHERE (c.`active` = 1 OR c.`id_category` = 2)
    AND cs.`id_category` = c.`id_category` AND cs.`id_shop` = 2
    AND c.`id_category` != 1
     AND `level_depth` <= 2
    AND c.id_category IN (SELECT id_category FROM `pj_category_group` WHERE `id_group` IN (3))
    ORDER BY c.`level_depth` ASC, cl.`name` ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks pradeep for your quick response.But i have a condition I do not make change in my query.

Answer (score 1):

Sql Feature Order by is as the name suggests used to order the Selected Columns on the basis of the Column mentioned in the below Syntax :
Order by Column_Name ASC/DESC

So if you don't add the column using which you have decided to retrieve order set of data in the select clause you will get this error.

Comment: Thanks Jayesh.But my query will work in mysql which are below verison number 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.id_parent, c.id_category, cl.name, cl.description, cl.link_rewrite
            FROM `pj_category_shop` cs, `pj_category` c
            INNER JOIN `pj_category_lang` cl ON (c.`id_category` = cl.`id_category` AND cl.`id_lang` = 1 AND cl.id_shop = 2 )
            WHERE (c.`active` = 1 OR c.`id_category` = 2)
            ORDER BY c.`level_depth` ASC, cl.`name` ASC
            AND cs.`id_category` = c.`id_category` AND cs.`id_shop` = 2
            AND c.`id_category` != 1
             AND `level_depth` <= 2
            AND c.id_category IN (SELECT id_category FROM `pj_category_group` WHERE `id_group` IN (3));
```

To summarize, you need to have the `ORDER BY` in the context of the `SELECT` command, in which case, with the `WHERE`, `FROM` and `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Linking together some threads here - i believe it has to do with mysql version (we were able to bypass by using 5.7) and/or strict mode: https://github.com/publiclab/plots2/pull/8145

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to bypass it. **It is not the best practice** that you can do ( I think that it is even worse... but if you don't have any control over your SQL_MODE it should work):

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.id_parent, d.id_category, d.name, d.description, d.link_rewrite
        FROM (select c.id_parent, c.id_category, cl.name, cl.description, cl.link_rewrite
        FROM   `pj_category_shop` cs, `pj_category` c
        INNER JOIN `pj_category_lang` cl ON (c.`id_category` = cl.`id_category` AND cl.`id_lang` = 1 AND cl.id_shop = 2 )
        WHERE (c.`active` = 1 OR c.`id_category` = 2)
        ORDER BY c.`level_depth` ASC, cl.`name` ASC
        AND cs.`id_category` = c.`id_category` AND cs.`id_shop` = 2
        AND c.`id_category` != 1
         AND `level_depth` <= 2
        AND c.id_category IN (SELECT id_category FROM `pj_category_group` WHERE `id_group` IN (3))) as d ;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can run :

```sql
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

But if you restart your server, you may have to re run it.

---

2. You can update the mysql server configuration:

- on Windows, the **${MY_SQL_HOME}/my.cnf** (or **my.ini**)
- on Linux, one of the following: **etc/my.cnf**, **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**, **/usr/etc/my.cnf** or **~/.my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]

# RESOLVE order-by-clause-is-not-in-select-list by removing ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from the sql-mode list
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```